# Multiple conditions for loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, loops

I have this code now:
This is iOS

```
   for(NSDictionary * dict in myMutableArray)
{
    NSString * str = [dict objectForKey:@"MyStringKey"];
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:str];
}
```

I need to also have a for loop like this:

```
NSInteger *count = [myMutableArray count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    arrayVar = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

I need to kind of combine these. I am inserting a segment into a UISegmentedControl while getting the name from a for loop which is looping through the array getting nsdictionary which is retrieving a nsstring that I will put into the uisegmentedcontrol.

So bottom line is I need to merge these for loops so I get the name like I do from the first for loop while still getting the objectatindex like it is in the second for loop.

How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are monLessonArrayA and myMutableArray the same array? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please tag this question with the language you're using?

Comment: yes they are the same will edit that in a second. And iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version you have will work just fine.
There is no way to access the index in the first version.
There is a newer syntax available if you like, that uses blocks:

```
  NSArray *array;
  [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    // whatever else
  }];
```

The main benefit of blocks is they can use multiple cores in your device more effectively.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using block. How would I conform your code to mine? This all looks like another language to me :P

Comment: change `array` to any array, change `dict` to any type object stored in that array, the `idx` is the index and you can ignore `stop` if you want to visit all the items in the array

Comment: you realize `arrayVar` in the second loop == `dict` in the first loop?